# Why model.predict returns 1 column of output for 10 classes?

Tags: python, keras, object-detection

I created my model and when I try a prediction, model.predict returns a value [0.09601733]] or something like that which is between 0 and 1. However I am making an object detection with 10 classes.So I am waiting some ouput like this:[0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.01, 0.2, 0.96, 0.01]

What might be the problem? Here is the related parts of the code:

```
train= pd.read_csv("C:/Users/yazilim1/Desktop/Jupyter/cifar-10/trainLabels.csv")
test= pd.read_csv("C:/Users/yazilim1/Desktop/Jupyter/cifar-10/trainLabels.csv")
for i in range(len(train.index)):
    train.iloc[i,0] = str( train.iloc[i,0])+".png"
#    print(train.iloc[i,0]
# Create a train data generator
train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=45, rescale=1./255, horizontal_flip=True)
#Create test data generator to test at the end (for predictions)
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1 / 255.0) #Rescale it to 1/255.
#Get the datas by using data generators we just created above
train_data = train_gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe= train, directory = ("C:/Users/yazilim1/Desktop/Jupyter/cifar-10/train/Edges"), x_col="id" , y_col="label",seed = 42,
batch_size = 64, shuffle = True, class_mode="categorical",target_size = (32, 32), color_mode="grayscale")
#Create a Verify data with Data Generator
verify_data = train_gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe= train, directory = ("C:/Users/yazilim1/Desktop/Jupyter/cifar-10/train/Edges"), x_col="id" , y_col="label",seed = 42,
batch_size = 64, shuffle = True, class_mode="categorical",target_size = (32, 32), color_mode="grayscale")


#Create Model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape=(32,32,1) ))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation("sigmoid"))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics =['accuracy'])
#Model fit
STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_data.n // train_data.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID= verify_data.n // verify_data.batch_size
model.fit(train_data,
                    steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                    validation_data=verify_data,
                    validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                    epochs=2,
                    verbose=1
                   )
score = model.evaluate_generator(valid_generator)
print('Test loss:', score[0])
print('Test accuracy:', score[1])


IMG_SIZE=32
test_images=[]

test_images_folder=[img for img in glob.glob("C:/Users/yazilim1/Desktop/Jupyter/cifar-10/train/Test/*")]
#image_folder= natural_sort(test_images_folder)
for test_image in test_images_folder:
    test_image= cv2.imread(test_image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
    test_image=cv2.resize(test_image, (IMG_SIZE, IMG_SIZE))
    test_image=np.reshape(test_image,[1,32,32,1])
    test_image=test_image/255
    test_images.append(test_image)
print("Number of Images added:" + str(len(test_images)))

print(model.predict(test_images[0]))
```

Comment: You're using Binary cross entropy as a loss, which is only for a 2-class classification problem, buy you've got a 10 class if I'm not wrong

Comment: Yes you are right there are 10 classes that I need to classifty. And also sigmoid cannot be used in here and I should be using softmax as activator. Am I right?

Comment: @GünkutAğabeyoğlu, yes and categorical_crossentropy. However, be the last layer must the number of classes you expect right?, so layer=10.

Comment: @coldy Thank you and where and how can I add that layer=10 part?

Comment: Its the number of units/neurons in the last layer.